# Highcharts rendered with no strokes using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: svg, charts, highcharts, wkhtmltopdf, stroke

I have an issue with generating PDF using wkhtmltopdf.
It's very similar to the case described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636599/highcharts-charts-on-a-page-not-rendering-correctly-when-output-to-pdf-using-wk), except first few charts are rendered fine, but after page break, each next is rendered without strokes - no axis, no ticks, no legend borders, etc.
Then third page with the rest of the charts is rendered fine.

Also -webkit-border-radius: 1px, described [here](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=329) didn't work:

Does anyone knows how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After two days I found the problem :

Demo with my case :

HTML :

```
<div class="graph">
 <div id="chart" style="width: 535px; height:275px;"><!-- chart render here --></div>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
.graph {
    position: relative;
}
```

Do not put the css position to "relative" and the chart will be correct on your pdf. Check on your code if the parent div is not on "relative".